# How to unprocess and full process a SSAS Cube

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas

I have a doubt regarding the cube unprocess and process full procedure that, Do I need to unprocess all dimensions and then only do unprocess to cube and after doing process full to all dimensions, then only I can do process full with cube.

Am I doing right? If not please suggest me the correct way to do unprocess and process full of the cube ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can find here :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174774.aspx

Process full :

> Processes an Analysis Services object and all the objects that it
>   contains. When Process Full is executed against an object that has
>   already been processed, Analysis Services **drops all data in the
>   object, and then processes the object**. This kind of processing is
>   required when a structural change has been made to an object, for
>   example, when an attribute hierarchy is added, deleted, or renamed.

So unprocess your cube is unnecessary.

If you want to  make simple, just Process Full you SSAS **Database**, Cube and Dimensions will be refreshed.

Hope this help,